# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined variable: actualLabels

Tags: php, laravel

Help, i got an error "ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined variable: actualLabels" in my code

```
$title = "Data Confusion Matrix";
$testing_data = DataTesting::count();
$klasifikasi = Klasifikasi::with('sentimen')->get();
foreach($klasifikasi as $kelas){
    $predictedLabels[] = $kelas->sentimen->kategori;
    $testing = DataTesting::where('id_testing',$kelas->id_testing)->first();
    $twitter = TwitterStream::with('sentimen')->where('id_crawling',$testing->id_crawling)->first();
    $actualLabels[] = $twitter->sentimen->kategori;
 }
 $getPrecision = new ControllerConfusionMatrix($actualLabels, $predictedLabels);
 $accuracy = ControllerConfusionMatrix::score($actualLabels, $predictedLabels);
 $recall = $getPrecision->getRecall();
 $precision = $getPrecision->getPrecision();
```

Comment: Put this line before foreach loop, `$actualLabels = [];`

Comment: @AksenP - about all we can do is just vote to close and move on then; doubtless there'll be some people answering to pick the "low hanging fruit" (unless the question is closed) - decreasing the overall quality/usefulness of SO going forward, but such is life.

Comment: @AksenP If you don't want to please don't insult, I really don't know how to fix the error

Comment: @Listyawan - to be fair, you've asked 4 questions in the last 2 days, all of which amount to the same thing - very basic undefined index/variable errors, for which there are already canonical QAs you should refer to. Having the same questions repeatedly asked on SO just increases the noise and thus reduces the quality of the site, as a resource, overall. Please refer to the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**define `Array()`**

```
$predictedLabels = array();
$actualLabels = array();
            foreach($klasifikasi as $kelas){
                $predictedLabels[] = $kelas->sentimen->kategori;
                $testing = DataTesting::where('id_testing',$kelas->id_testing)->first();
                $twitter = TwitterStream::with('sentimen')->where('id_crawling',$testing->id_crawling)->first();
                $actualLabels[] = $twitter->sentimen->kategori;
            }
```

Comment: you should explain why your answer is supposed to work. Code only answers are poor quality ones

Comment: @Vikas Katariya Thank you very much

Comment: please select this answer.

Comment: @VikasKatariya it is not a game to who answers first. Also the accepted answer has a better quality and explains the issue and the solution to the OP that can learn from that (yours doesn't). You should know how SO works since you are not a newbie on the site

Comment: Thank you so much please give upvote this answer @Listyawan

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to beginning of your code : `$actualLabels = [];`
You are getting error because when `$klasifikasi` is empty, then the statement inside loop is not executed. So `$actualLabels` variable is not created. In this case you get errro of `(E_NOTICE) Undefined variable: actualLabels`.
Hope you understand.

Comment: @Listyawan welcome sir and enjoy coding